# Washing machine timer

Tags: washing-machine, timer

I've been trouble-shooting an 18 year old Electrolux washing machine. The model is Simpson Eziset 36S550L*01. It seems the problem is most likely a faulty timer.

Some websites and videos I've seen show the timer as a separate unit that can removed and tested on its own but the machine I'm working on doesn't appear to have anything like that.

I've included pictures of the control board below.

Does anyone know what kind of timer this machine has and whether it can be tested/replaced separately or would the control board need to be replaced?

[image: back]

[image: front]

Comment: It looks like a single piece unit.  An electronics repair shop could probably test and replace the timer, but for most other people would need a control board replacement(which might be cheaper).

Comment: Could you included the model number of the machine?

Comment: What are the symptoms?

Comment: @JACK, I've edited the question to include the model number.

Comment: @HandyHowie, The symptoms are taking too long to finish or skipping some parts of the wash cycle.

Comment: agree with @crip659.  It is appealing to fix things but the labor cost will be more than ordering a new or salvaged board.  Those are easy to replace.  I have good memories of lowering my third grader back behind the washer to do that fix.

Comment: @Willk  Small ones are so handy to have.  Their hands can fit almost in anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odds of an end-user being able to test this board to find the error, then replace the failed part are extremely low. Even if you can identify which individual component has failed, the odds of being able to purchase just the part in question at a reasonable price are probably quite low.

Appliance repair shops with the knowledge and skills to do this testing are extremely few and far between.

This is designed to be replaced as an assembly, not as individual components. Since it appears that your first picture is from a parts supply warehouse of some sort (based on the partial watermark visible) just order the board assembly (probably complete with the plastic housing) then, when the new one comes in, replace the old one and chuck it.

Technically, I suppose you should take it to an electronics recycling place. (Thrown in to avoid making people grumpy, though few actually will take something like this to an approved recycling facility.)